# Process threads stuck with __pthread_enable_asynccancel ()

Tags: c, pthreads, syslog

I am debugging an issue with a multi-threaded TCP server application on CentOS platform. The application suddenly stopped processing connections. Even the event logging with `syslog` was not seen in the log files. It was as if the application become a black hole.

I killed the process with signal 11 to get the core dump. In the core dump I observed that all threads are stuck with similar patterns.

Ex:

```
Thread 19 (Thread 0xb2de8b70 (LWP 3722)):
#0  0x00c9e424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x00c17189 in __pthread_enable_asynccancel () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x080b367d in server_debug_stats_timer_handler (tmp=0x0) at server_debug_utils.c:75 ==> this line as a event print with syslog(...)
```

All most all threads are attempting a `syslog(...)` print but gets stuck with `__pthread_enable_asynccancel ()`.

What is being done with `__pthread_enable_asynccancel ()` and why it isn't returning?

Here is info reg from the thread mentioned:

```
(gdb) info reg
eax            0xfffffe00       -512
ecx            0x80     128
edx            0x2      2
ebx            0x154ea3c4       357475268
esp            0xb2de8174       0xb2de8174
ebp            0xb2de81a8       0xb2de81a8
esi            0x0      0
edi            0x0      0
eip            0xc9e424 0xc9e424 <__kernel_vsyscall+16>
eflags         0x200246 [ PF ZF IF ID ]
cs             0x73     115
ss             0x7b     123
ds             0x7b     123
es             0x7b     123
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x33     51
(gdb)

(gdb) print $orig_eax
$1 = 240
```

(`$orig_eax = 240` is `SYS_futex`)

One of the thread state is as shown below:

```
    Thread 27 (Thread 0xa97d9b70 (LWP 3737)):
#0  0x00c9e424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x00faabb3 in inet_ntop () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x00f20e76 in freopen64 () from /lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x00f96a55 in fcvt_r () from /lib/libc.so.6
#4  0x00f96fd7 in qfcvt_r () from /lib/libc.so.6
#5  0x00a19932 in app_signal_handler (signum=11) at appBaseClass.cpp:920
#6  <signal handler called>
#7  0x00f2aec5 in sYSMALLOc () from /lib/libc.so.6
#8  0x0043431a in CRYPTO_free () from /usr/local/lr/packages/stg_app/5.3.8/lib/ssl/libcrypto.so.10
#9  0x00000000 in ?? ()

(gdb) print $orig_eax $5 = 240`
```

Comment: The threads are stuck in a syscall, and `__pthread_enable_asynccancel` doesn't call any syscalls, so the stack trace is not entirely accurate.  Can you use `strace -p <pid>` to see what syscall the threads are in?

Comment: @caf, The problem occurred in field once. I am not able to reproduce the case in-house. My mistake. I should have used `strace` before killing the process..

Comment: If you still have the coredump, you can find out which syscall was being called by examining the register state.  Can you add the output of the gdb command `info reg` from a representative thread?

Comment: @caf, I have updated the question with info reg

Comment: Sorry, could you also add the output of `print $orig_eax` in gdb on that thread?

Comment: @caf, updated with `$orig_eax` info. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122960/discussion-between-prabhu-and-caf).

Comment: @caf, any thoughts on why many threads are having `__pthread_enable_asynccancel`? Does it mean that some thread is trying to cancel other threads for some reason?

Comment: Calls to `__pthread_enable_asynccancel()` are expected just before system calls, because it's just how glibc implements the fact that many system calls are cancellation points.  Does your `server_debug_stats_timer_handler()` function call any pthreads functions?

Comment: Also, where is `server_debug_stats_timer_handler()` being called from - a signal handler?

Comment: @caf, no. It is called by the timer thread at the application. At set intervals, it will print the debug logs. I have indicated one another thread, which I believe caught the sig-11 when I did `kill -11 <pid>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stuck threads are in the `futex()` syscall, probably on an internal glibc lock taken within `malloc()` (the `syslog()` call allocates memory internally).

The reason for this deadlock isn't apparent, but I have two suggestions:

- If you call `syslog()` (or any other non-AS-safe function, like `printf()`) from a signal handler anywhere in your program, that could cause a deadlock like this;
- It's possible you're being bitten by a [bug in `futex()`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mechanical-sympathy/QbmpZxp6C64) that was introduced in Linux 3.14 and fixed in 3.18.  The bug was also backported RHEL 6.6 so would have been present for a while in CentOS too.  The effect of this bug was to cause processes to fail to wake up from a `FUTEX_WAIT` when they should have.